# Trying to access RTDB from a container-based VM with appropriate privileged service account errors on invalid credentials

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

We're running a container based VM, with associated service account which has appropriate permissions to write to realtime database ("Firebase Realtime Database Admin") and more.
The service account also has "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs" enabled.

From the container we initialize Firebase admin SDK, and then trying to set a value on an RTDB node.

```
const app = admin.initializeApp({
   projectId: '<MY-PROJECT>',
   databaseURL: 'https://<MY-PROJECT>-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com',
});
await app.database().ref('test').set('abc');
```

When this code runs, it produces the following error:

> @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Provided authentication credentials for the app named "[DEFAULT]" are invalid. This usually indicates your app was not initialized correctly. Make sure the "credential" property provided to initializeApp() is authorized to access the specified "databaseURL" and is from the correct project.

The credentials are missing from the `initializeApp` call intentionally, as we rely on [Google Application Default Credentials (ADC)](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials#attached-sa) to use the associated service account correctly.

We want to avoid saving the credentials json file on the container.

Important notes:

1. Setting a value to a Firestore document (using the code below) works perfectly (data is saved in Firestore).

```
await app.firestore().doc('test/doc').set({ test: 'abc' });
```

2. When I use credentials json file for the used service account (by setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`), it works (data is saved in RTDB).

How can I use the service account correctly without using the credentials json?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after posting the question, I found it's a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69285140/google-compute-engine-firebase-database-firebase-warning).
Solution is:

```
gcloud compute instances set-service-account [INSTANCE_NAME] \
  --service-account "your.gserviceaccount.com" \
  --scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
```